# Как создать плавающую кнопку для сайта?

Tags: wordpress, веб-программирование, wordpress-плагины, плагин

Всем привет, заказчик хочет плавающую кнопку на сайте, при клике на которую появится окно с формой. На данный момент, сама форма готова. Осталась проблема с самой кнопкой, с помощью плагина(Popup maker) могу на любой элемент привязать форму(она появляется при клике), вот только с самой кнопки проблема, не могу найти плагин, который бы полностью подошел в решения задачи, пробовал писать код на прямую, кнопку выводит, вот только стили для нее не видит, подскажите, как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Подключить стили кнопки. Вы уверены, что правильно подключаете файл стилей кнопки, и смотрите без кеша результат?

Answer (score 0):

А в чем проблема описать форму в footer.php перед

например:

```
<div id="call_modal">Кнопка</div>
```

На это ID навязать стили что бы зафиксировать её и красивости на усмотрение

```
#call_modal {position:fixed; right:10px; bottom:10px;}
```

Потом навязать JQuery для открытия модалки?

```
$('#call_modal').click(function(){
   $('.modal_class').addClass('open')
})
```

- Работает при условии открытия(показа) модалки с помощью класса 'open'